# I'm getting the Mixed content Error how can I let node_modules or Laravel to allow me to make api calls over https?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, heroku, https, axios

[image][image]I'm using laravel for api and axios with react for the api calls on heroku. My site is being loaded over https. My endpoint is supposedly using http according to the Mixed Content Error, although I'm using axios's 'baseURL' to make a call using https.

axios({
  method: 'POST'
  baseURL: 'https://item-manager-api-client.herokuapp.com',
})

I've tried using ajax also to see why the mixed content error is giving me the http detail even though I'm using https in my api calls. I changed my APP_URL config variable with the heroku cli too. I've also changed the baseURL in axios again and purposely used the wrong site reference and that edit showed up in the Mixed Content error, but yet the https edit is not showing up in the error. I'm guessing somewhere in the node_modules it's configuring my api calls somehow.

Comment: Look in your browser's network panel and look at the API requests first.

Comment: @ceejayoz  Sorry I'm not too familiar with the network panel. but this is what I see in there,(pic of network panel added above) any chance something looks odd to you in it? Thanks.